# Computing $\max_{z\in S^1}|z^2\bar{f}(x)-f(x)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, optimization

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $z\in S^1$ is the unit circle. Is it easy to compute
$$\max_{z\in S^1}|z^2\bar{f}(x)-f(x)|.$$
Note that $f$ is independent of $z$. I suspect not but perhaps I'm overlooking something rather simple. We know that
\begin{align*}
\max_{z\in S^1}|z^2\bar{f}(x)-f(x)| &\leq \max_{z\in S^1}|z^2\bar{f}(x)|+|f(x)|\\
&=2|f(x)|
\end{align*}
but this is only an upper bound. Is there a way to compute this value directly?

Comment: You can choose $z \in S^1$ such that $z^2 \bar f(x) = - f(x)$, which shows that your upper bound *is* the maximum.

Comment: Awesome! So $2|f(x)|$ would indeed be our maximum since we can take $z^2=-f(x)/\bar{f}(x)$ and $-f(x)/\bar{f}(x)\in S^1$ since $|f/\bar{f}|=|f/f|=1$ for $f\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$ and let $c=f(x)$. For every $z \in \mathbb{S}_1$,
$$|z^2\overline{c}-c| = |z\overline{c}-cz^{-1}| 
= |z\overline{c}-c\overline{z}| = |2\Im(z\overline{c})| \le 2|z\overline{c}| = 2|c|,$$
and equality holds if and only the half line $z\mathbb{R}_+$ contains $c$.

Comment: Wouldn't $|z^2\bar{c}-c|=2|Im(z\bar{c})|\implies \max_{z\in S^1}|z^2\bar{c}-c|=2|Im(\bar{c})| \max_{z\in S^1}|Im(z)|=2|Im(\bar{c})|$? Perhaps this is what you mean by your last statement and this is just phrasing it differently?

Comment: If $c \ne 0$, look at $z_0:=c/|c|$.